# Comparing digits in an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Really need some help here. Super early in learning Python.

The goal is to take a number and see if the digits are in ascending order.
What I have so far is:

```
a = int(input("Enter a 4-digit number: "))

b = [int(i) for i in str(a)]

if b[0] > b[1]:
    print "Not ascending"
elif b[1] > b[2]:
    print "Not ascending"
elif b[2] > b[3]:
    print "Not ascending"
else:
    print "Ascending!"
```

My question is, how can I make it so that there's no limit on the amount  of digits entered? So if someone enters a 7 digit number it does the same process up to the last digit.

Comment: use [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loops

Comment: `"".join(sorted(a)) == a`

Comment: Keep the input as string and `list(a) == sorted(list(a))`.

Comment: half-dupe of [How can I determine if the numbers in a list initially increase (or stay the same) and then decrease (or stay the same) with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50012089/674039)

Comment: @wim. Saw that too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to check list monotonicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983258/python-how-to-check-list-monotonicity)

Comment: As a side-note: if you start learning Python, learn Python 3, not 2 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

First step sort all your input

```
b = [int(i) for i in str(a)]
```

Second step, compare the origin input with the sorted-list, all the element of the list can be concat with a string (digit-string), so you can compare them with only one time.

```
c = sorted(b)

''.join([str(i) for i in b]) > ''.join([str(i) for i in c]):

   print "Not ascending"
else:
   print "Ascending!"
```

Or use the std lib, check every element with the next element just like your way:

```
every_check = [b[i] <= b[i+1] for i in xrange(len(b)-1)]
```

> [True, True, False, False]

and use `all()` check if all `True`

```
if all(every_check):
    print "Ascending!"
else:
    print "Not ascending"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a loop.

for example:

```
a = int(input("Enter a 4-digit number: "))

b = [int(i) for i in str(a)]


def isAscending(b):
  #loop for as many digits in the array
  for x in range(0, len(b) - 1):
    # if the next number is less than the previous return false
    if b[x] > b[x+1]:
      return False
  #  did not fail so return true
  return True

if isAscending(b):
  print ("the number is in ascending order")
else:
  print ("the number is not in ascending order")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with such a small number of digits, just create a new list w/ the elements in ascending order. Fortunately, Python has a function that does exactly that, the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
def is_ascending(lst):
    return sorted(lst) == lst
```